Lateral Stability- Why aircraft will not return of its own accord to the original heading after a sideway gust?
I am reading the Stability section of FAA it says:

If an aircraft is flying in a straight line, and a sideward gust
of air gives the aircraft a slight rotation about its vertical
axis (i.e., the right), the motion is retarded and stopped by
the fin because while the aircraft is rotating to the right, the
air is striking the left side of the fin at an angle. This causes
pressure on the left side of the fin, which resists the turning
motion and slows down the aircraft’s yaw. In doing so, it
acts somewhat like the weather vane by turning the aircraft
into the relative wind.
The initial change in direction of the
aircraft’s flight path is generally slightly behind its change
of heading. Therefore, after a slight yawing of the aircraft
to the right, there is a brief moment when the aircraft is still
moving along its original path, but its longitudinal axis is
pointed slightly to the right.


The aircraft is then momentarily skidding sideways and,
during that moment (since it is assumed that although the
yawing motion has stopped, the excess pressure on the left
side of the fin still persists), there is necessarily a tendency
for the aircraft to be turned partially back to the left. That is,
there is a momentary restoring tendency caused by the fin.
This restoring tendency is relatively slow in developing and
ceases when the aircraft stops skidding. When it ceases, the
aircraft is flying in a direction slightly different from the
original direction. In other words, it will not return of its own
accord to the original heading; the pilot must reestablish the
initial heading.

I am not quite understanding the last section: why aircraft will not return of its own accord to the original heading after a sideway gust?

The paragraph is actually talking about directional static stability, or yawing moment due to sideslip angle β ($C_n$β as aerodynamic coefficient). A positive directional static stability tends to return the aircraft to zero sideslip (β=0) if any sideslip disturbance occurs, due to the lift and drag generated by the vertical tail if any β is present.
The lift and drag by the vertical tail also creates a side force ($C_Y$β as aerodynamic coefficient) that offsets the velocity vector. So when β is reduced to 0, the heading has also changed due to a change in velocity vector.

Maybe an easier way of understanding this is to consider the case where the gust doesn't end.
This is called "crabbing" from the ground reference but the plane will simply fly a heading and the ground track is a combination of the airspeed and wind vectors.
Now back to the "gust".  Before it hits the plane is on on ground track based on the wind (could be 0) and it's airspeed.
The gust changes the relative wind so the planes directional stability tries to align it in a new direction.
As the gust passes, only thrust is acting on the plane.  Relative wind returns to the longitudinal axis of the aircraft, but the gust has caused some lateral rotation, or yaw.
Once the gust forces are gone, the plane flies straight away in a new direction.  It would take an equal gust, from the opposite direction, or control inputs, to return it to its original course.
